# Get the SMTP sender address from new opened Outlook mail inspector with C# (VSTO or redemption) when multiple accounts configured

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto, outlook-redemption

I've tried different approaches but I could not find a way to determine the sender address reliable from Outlook 2007 up to Outlook 2013 when multiple accounts can be selected in Outlook.

My addin is build on Add-In Express.

The aim is to get the account sender address from an active **new** mailitem (active mailinspector).

```
inspector = (AddinModule.CurrentInstance.OutlookApp as Outlook.Application).ActiveInspector();
mailitem = inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
```

In Outlook 2013 it is possible to use:

```
mailitem.SendUsingAccount.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address
```

What can I do to get the sender address when my add-in is running on Outlook 2010 or 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendUsingAccount was added in Outlook 2007, so you should be good.
I am not sure why you would want to use `mailitem.SendUsingAccount.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address` - you will always get the address of the default Outlook account.
Have you tried to use `mailitem.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress`?

Comment: Thanks for your passion! It's strange. The SendUsingAccount property is null till I changed the sender address in the mail inspector by clicking the "from" dropdown. How to fix this problem?

Comment: Do you have any idea why this property is null? Thanks!

Comment: Unless the account was explicitly set, you will get back null. In that case you can assume that the default account was used.

Comment: Ok - I'll take the default account address if the value is null. thank you very much!